# Up to what extent is drawing living things permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, image, soul, drawing

What is Islamic ruling on the drawing of the shape/body of an object? Is it true that the objects could be living objects with a soul as long as no face is drawn?

Or in general, can we draw a living thing, as long was we don't have a bad intention?  Perhaps without drawing the face, or without eyes (face present).

Or if it doesn't make it too broad, on what extent can one draw images of living things.

Or simply, is drawing every living thing prohibited in Islam according to Hadith in this [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/11157/11938) for the question [Can I draw living creatures just for art?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11153)

Please cite some Hadith while answering, or any scholarly rulings present in this regards.

Comment: What are the things that have souls?

Comment: I am not clear about exact reference. So far I heard they are animals but not plants or anything else. Correct me if I am wrong jazaklahir