# Can I draw living creatures just for art?

Tags: halal-haram, image, drawing

Can I draw living creatures just for art? I was thinking about making a comic book. I am not trying to perfect or copy Allah's creation or anything.

Comment: AFAIK. Yes you can. No harm in it.

Comment: Drawing is allowed within some condition according to Yusuf Al Qaradawi's book "Lawful and Prohibited in Islam" this is the link to read those conditions [Seek and scroll down almost one-third of this page to get the relevant topic]>>>http://bit.ly/1Ltg56h

Answer (score 4):

It depends on if what you draw is used as objects of worship by other religions or not. Also depends on which scholar or Marja you follow for Islamic laws.

> It is forbidden to make a complete statue or sculpture of a living
>   being.  However, there is no problem in buying or selling pictures of
>   such statues or sculptures, even though it is Makrooh. Making a
>   sculpture of a limb by itself is permissible.
>
> Drawing, painting or carving a living being is permissible. 
>   Similarly, making statues or sculptures of non-living things like
>   flowers or trees is permissible.
>
> Sculpting, painting or drawing of living or non-living things or
>   symbols that are used as objects of worship by other religions is not
>   allowed.  So making, buying or selling idols or religious symbols such
>   as a cross would not be permissible.

---

**References:**

- [Business Moral Codes in Islam](http://www.islamic-laws.com/download/Business%20Moral%20Codes%20in%20Islam.doc)
- [['Aalim Network QR] Painting, Drawing, Sculptures.](http://www.al-islam.org/organizations/AalimNetwork/msg00254.html)

Comment: good answer, also maybe you would like to complete your answer by bringing about the Hadeeth interpreting that verse of Quran that the holiness Solomon decorated his castle with paintings (of trees and flowers). Also about dolls I asked Imam Khamenei for Fatwa and his representative answered no one today will ban such things.

Comment: So what u're saying is, drawing and painting realistic portraits of animate things is haram although buying/selling such things isn't cuz it's not you who painted it?? But don't u think buying/selling these supports the work of something who is doing something haram.

Answer (score 3):

No it, is not ok to draw living creatures just for art or for any other reasons, as it has been narrated in it's forbidden.  But if you want to or must draw art, then you can draw like trees or the sky or rocks or buildings etc, as long it is not creature like human or animal.

> كل مصور في النار يجعل له بكل صورة صورها نفس فيعذبه في جهنم‏"‏ قال ابن
>   عباس‏:‏ فإن كنت لابد فاعلا، فاصنع الشجر وما لا ورح فيه
>
> Every painter will go to Hell, and for every portrait he has made,
>   there will be appointed one who will chastise him in the Hell." Ibn
>   'Abbas said: If you have to do it, draw pictures of trees and other
>   inanimate things.

[رياض الصالحين](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18/170)

Comment: I believe this hadith is a fake.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs If you can bring the proof hat it is fake then ok, but there is no proof that it is fake.

Comment: i don't know if it's fake or not but in early islamic arts faces were left out of most humans..especially Prophet Muhammad PBUH and his companions. Maybe it was because of this..who knows i am not a historian of any type. But i am glad though...if photo had been drawn then people would for sure hanging that photo in houses and praying to it and there would be million stories how with barakat of this photo everything get better.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs This is very wrong to call a Hadith 'Fake'. You have to show proof/evidence about whatever you claim because if by any chance the hadith is authentic, you are thrown outta the bounds of Islam for being a 'Munkar' of hadith even if its one. Just say maybe the Hadith is da'ef/weak narration-wise. If you must say its fabricated then have proof as backup so your own 'emaan' does not get endangered. I hope I made sense.