# Drew animate things before knowing it is sin

Tags: fatwa, animals, drawing

Jazakallah khair i really appreciate this but im still confused is it haraam to have animal statues?

Comment: Well don't forget that it's your intention that counts first, and then i doubt whether you would worship an owl ornament or a painting. But you still could explain your POV!

Comment: Maybe relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11153/drawing-living-things, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11826/where-exactly-does-the-quran-or-hadith-say-that-picture-making-is-a-sin and maybe http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-drawing-people-prohibited-in-islam

Answer (score -2):

making or sketching picture of any living thing is prohibited in islam. same as to make statue or such things are also not allowed.

I want to give reference from Quran to support my answer
Surah Al-R'af :
The people of Moses made, in his absence, out of their ornaments the image of a calf. It seemed to low. Did they not see that it could not speak, not guide them on the way. They took it for worship and they did wrong.

i also want to give some references from hadiths:
We were with Masruq at the house of Yasar bin Numair. Masruq saw pictures on his terrace and said, "I heard 'Abdullah saying that he heard the Prophet saying, "The people who will receive the severest punishment from Allah will be the picture makers.'" (Narrated by Muslim)

Hadith 7,838 (Al-Bukhari)

Ibn e Abbas narrated I heard Muhammad saww saying, "Whoever makes a picture in this world will be asked to put life into it on the Day of Resurrection, but he will not be able to do so."

you can also visit this reference to read more about picturesin Islam
http://sunnahonline.com/library/fiqh-and-sunnah/130-ahadith-concerning-taswir-pictures